# Time 2 hours off after computer is turned off

Tags: bios

I have a new Gigabyte motherboard (B660M ds3h ax) that loses 2 hours on the clock in the bios.
It does this when the computer is turned off overnight.
I do think it loses exactly 2 hours.
What can I do to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is it dual boot with Windows? What is the hardware, a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Intel I3 121000 cpu

Comment: I prefer to edit the Windows registry to change Windows to UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly 2 hours smells like the bios and computer disagree about local time vs utc and/or which timezone you're in. The `hwclock` command can help you make them agree with each other.

Comment: I do apologize. I am using Win 11. It looks like the bios is reporting right. I changed the setting in os to automatic. I changed my time zone to central.

Comment: Thanks alot, it appears to be holding.

Comment: It also looks like I needed to correct the time in bios each time it started. It is good now.

Comment: Edit Windows Registry using the method shown in the link in user68186's comment, in the first answer under the paragraph  **Make Windows use UTC**. This fix has worked for me for many years.